# Postgresql node traversal using Recursive CTE

Tags: postgresql

I am just trying to learn graph traversal using Recursive CTE in postgresql.

Below is my data set:

[image]

i am using the below code to get the path along with existing columns(node & edges).
It is giving me output but path column is not in ARRAY format.

```
    ;WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
(
    SELECT NODE,EDGES,ARRAY[G.NODE]::TEXT AS PATH,1 AS LEVEL
    FROM property_graph G
    UNION ALL
    SELECT G.NODE,G.EDGES,C.PATH || G.NODE,LEVEL + 1
    FROM property_graph G
    INNER JOIN CTE C ON G.NODE = ANY(C.EDGES)
    WHERE G.NODE <> ALL(STRING_TO_ARRAY(C.PATH,'')) --Cond added to avoid cyclic graph
)
SELECT NODE,EDGES,PATH,LEVEL
FROM CTE
ORDER BY NODE,LEVEL;
```

Output:
[image]

Could you guys help me?

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `PATH` column is of type `TEXT`, and so is `NODE`, therefore the `||` operator performs string concatenation rather than array concatenation.

You should change the type of your `PATH` column from `TEXT` to `TEXT[]` (and then you can remove the `STRING_TO_ARRAY` in the `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
(
    SELECT NODE,EDGES,ARRAY[G.NODE]::TEXT[] AS PATH,1 AS LEVEL
    FROM property_graph G
    UNION ALL
    SELECT G.NODE,G.EDGES,C.PATH || ARRAY[G.NODE]::TEXT[],LEVEL + 1
    FROM property_graph G
    INNER JOIN CTE C ON G.NODE = ANY(C.EDGES)
    WHERE G.NODE <> ALL(C.PATH) --Cond added to avoid cyclic graph
)
SELECT NODE,EDGES,PATH,LEVEL
FROM CTE
ORDER BY NODE,LEVEL;
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay but getting below error on line ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] || character varying
LINE 6:     SELECT G.NODE,G.EDGES,C.PATH || G.NODE,LEVEL + 1

Comment: UNION ALL
SELECT G.NODE,G.EDGES,C.PATH || ARRAY[G.NODE]::TEXT[],LEVEL + 1...with this changes...it worked for me